# Why pull with conflicts after amend?

Tags: git

So... 
git with `develop` and `master` and `feature/XYZ-123` branches.

1. Check out `feature/XYZ-123`.
2. Make a simple one line change.
3. Commit and push.
4. Realize you didn't get it quite right and make some more changes to the same line.
5. Amend your commit and then try to push but you get:

   ```
   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
   ```

Do a pull as instructed and you wind up with conflicts. Why??

Comment: It sounds like someone else may have pushed to that same feature branch between your two commits, and modified the file that you've been working on.

Comment: you don't need pull, but need push force: `git push -f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you do an "amend" (instead of making a new commit with your second edit), it will re-write the sha of the commit. This new commit conflicts with the remote head because it has the same parent as the remote commit, but changes on the same lines.

The solution to this is either:

- Do not ammend commits, just make a new commit and push that to the remote

or

- Ammed the commit, but do a force push of the branch to the remote. This is slightly more risky, and you should only do this once you fully understand the downsides. For example, if someone else is collaborating on this branch, you could delete their commits. When doing a force push, a safer option than `--force` is `--force-with-lease`. [Disussion about force-with-lease here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/).

Comment: To add to this, there's a sort of compromise form of force-push, which is called `--force-with-lease`. What it does is *check* that the other Git has no new commits, and if so, do the force-push. If there are new (e.g., collaborator) commits that you'd lose, the force-with-lease fails like a regular non-forced push.